# When a syntax error occurs in the declaration declare postgresql

Tags: postgresql, syntax, plpgsql, declare

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_SplitArrayStr( anyelement , anyelement )
RETURNS anyarray 
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS $$
DECLARE f1 text , f2  text ; 
BEGIN
    f1 := $1::text ; 
    f2 := $2::text ; 
    SELECT * FROM UNNEST( string_to_array(f1, f2) ) as c1 ; 
END ;
$$;
```

> ERROR : Syntax error at or near "text"
>   LINE 2 : DECLARE f1  text , f2  text ;

How do I change?

Comment: declarations need to be separated with `;` see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html plus: SQL doesn't support variables only PL/pgSQL

Answer (score 4):

I see two issues:

1. wrong language specification - PostgreSQL native procedural language is **plpgsql**.
2. [`DECLARE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) uses semicolon for separation between individual variable declarations.

   ```
   postgres=# create or replace function foo()
   returns int as $$
   declare a int; b int;
   begin 
     a := 10; b := 20;
     return a + b;
   end;
   $$ language plpgsql;
   CREATE FUNCTION

   postgres=# select foo();
   ┌─────┐
   │ foo │
   ╞═════╡
   │  30 │
   └─────┘
   (1 row)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try  to specify the language at the end of the procedure 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Answer (score 0):

You've written PL/PgSQL code but marked it `LANGUAGE SQL`. Use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` if you're writing pl/pgsql functions.

Comment: Language sql -> Language plpgsql use !!! Syntax error at or near ","  Line 2 : Declare f1 text , f2 text

Comment: @JongpyoJeon Yes, because your code isn't valid plpgsql, declarations are separated by semicolons `;` not commas `,`. But that's why you got the *first* error. You should probably try reading the manual and examples.